# Is it possible to link Linux static C++ library at runtime?

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries

I know that the question is strange because we all know that a static `.a` library can be linked only at compile time.

I have a confidential code that I cannot share, but my question is what can let a code compiles and links against a static library successfully, but at runtime it complains about a missing symbol that is present in the `.a` lib which was linked with the code in the first place ?

What I can share is a little:

```
add_library(${NAME} STATIC ${NAME_SOURCES})
```

then this library is added to a global variable called `LIBS` that has all libraries needed to link to final binary.

I found the static library and I did an `objdump` on it and found the missing symbol.

So, it compiled the static lib then it compiled the final binary using that library, so why it complains about not finding it at runtime ?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a Scooby-Doo mystery that only you can solve, only you have complete access to all files and scripts. If "a code compiles and links against a static library successfully", then it must mean that all references have been resolved by the linker. There cannot be "a missing symbol that is present in the .a lib", by definition. Something about your assumptions is false. Either the code wasn't linked correctly, or the missing symbol comes from some other ***shared*** library. A failure to run an executable due to a "missing symbol" is always related to shared library linkage.

Comment: Yes, I am very confused as well, I do really well that the question should not be asked, but I am stuck with a confidential code, but I can ensure that the situation is exactly as I described, compilation passes, but execution fails, can't be linked with static and then looking for a shared lib?

Comment: Well, something about the situation is definitely not "exactly" as "described". This is a certainty. You should to set aside all your assumptions, and inspect every detail, from start to finish. At "runtime" any complaints about unresolved symbols reference a shared library. Full stop. End Of Story. The End. You will not get a different answer from anyone else. Because that's what it is.

Comment: Your program's compile time is the compiler's runtime. If your program is a compiler, or to be more precise, a linker (at least partially) then it can load a static library at run time. (That was about the title. The body of the question has nothing to do with it.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to cause this behaviour, here's one.

Suppose you have a shared library `libA.so` and a static library `libB.a`. Both export the same symbol `foo`.

```
// foo.c
void foo() {}

gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so foo.c
gcc -c foo.c && ar r libB.a foo.o
```

You link your program against both libraries:

```
// main.c
extern void foo();
int main() { foo(); }

gcc -o myexe main.c -L. -lA -lB -Wl,-rpath=. # dangerous, do not really do this
```

`foo` is resolved against `libA.so`.

Now suppose that at run time you have a different version of `libA.so`, one that does not export `foo`. Perhaps you have several versions of the library lying around, or maybe there is a software update.

```
// foo.c v2.0
void nofoo() {}

gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so foo.c
```

When you try to run `myexe`, the system will complain about

```
./myexe: symbol lookup error: ./myexe: undefined symbol: foo
```

`myexe` is linked againsg `libB.a` which defines `foo`, but as you can see, this doesn't help one little bit.